# Can we implement a UML profile on Conflicting NFRs using MDSE approach?

Tags: eclipse, uml, profiling, bpmn

Can we implement a UML profile on Conflicting NFRs using MDSE approach? I am just aimed at "detection & resolution of conflicting NFRs using UML profile & generating a business model then", is this idea implementable ???

Comment: MDSE?  Does that mean model driven software engineering (just guessing)?

Comment: In theory anything's possible. What is your context, what are your constraints?

Comment: MDSE means Model Driver Software Engineering

Comment: I just not sure about context, but it may be business process